# Is there a way to move a std::tuple into a struct?

Tags: c++

Say I have a struct and a tuple with identical fields:

```
struct foo {
  int x;
  std::string y;
  some_big_type z;
};

std::tuple<int, std::string> a{1, "hello", some_big_type{...}};
```

Is there a way to move-construct a foo object using a? By which I mean, I don't want to allocate new memory for a foo, but rather to construct a foo which acts as a "view" on the already-allocated tuple.

Comment: Writing a move-constructor? It's unclear what you actually want to do, because moving an `int` and a `double` is just copying.

Comment: Edited toy case to include types where copying is expensive, and edited question for clarity...

Comment: The question became even less clear. Do you want to move the tuple into the struct, effectively making the tuple "empty" (moved-from), or do you want the struct to be a view, as in reference the tuple, like a `std:string_view` typically references a `std::string`?

Comment: So you want to keep the original tuple intact?  In that case, you're not moving from it at all.

Comment: Since C++20 this is easy since [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) can then use parenthesis not only braces, so [std::make_from_tuple](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/make_from_tuple) can be used https://godbolt.org/z/W1ndhqPMa for earlier versions of standard something have to be handcrafted or respective constructor for `foo` provided.

Comment: @OP the `foo` is not a view by itself at all. Also note that `std::make_from_tuple` does not work per-type (which I assume when read the question), it just use aggregate initialization.

Comment: One option (or rather alternative) would be for `foo` to just hold reference members and then add a constructor that takes a tuple and initializes the references. That requires the tuple  to stay alive, but would make `foo` a quite cheap "view" of the tuple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) this is just `std::make_from_tuple<foo>(a)`.

Prior to [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) you have to write your own helper.

```
template<class T, std::size_t...Is, class Tuple>
T aggregate_from_tuple( std::index_sequence<Is...>, Tuple&& tuple ) {
  return { std::get<Is>( std::forward<Tuple>(tuple) )... };
}
template<class T, class Tuple>
T aggregate_from_tuple( Tuple&& tuple ) {
  auto indexes = std::make_index_sequence<
    std::tuple_size_v<std::decay_t<Tuple>>
  >{};
  return aggregate_from_tuple<T>(indexes, std::forward<Tuple>(tuple))
}
```

which is basically `make_from_tuple` with `()` replaced with `{}`.  In [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) you can use `()` to initialize aggregates.

The older the version of C++ it is the more verbose the above is going to get.  Prior to [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) I am not sure I could do it; the above is probably [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17).

This does NOT produce a *view* into the tuple.  It either copies it to a `foo` or (if you use `std::move`) moves it into the `foo`.

Often moving a type is cheap when copying is expensive.

There is no great way to create a view.  But a non-great way is this:

```
struct foo_view {
  int& x;
  std::string& y;
  some_big_type& z;
};
```

which isn't your `foo` type.  This is a non-owning view of something.

Then you use `aggregate_from_tuple` (or `make_from_tuple`) the same way, and you'll get an object that provides (near zero) cost renames.

Comment: This is exactly the answer to the question I was trying to ask.

Comment: Does this actually meet the "don't want to allocate new memory for a foo, but rather to construct a foo which acts as a 'view' on the already-allocated tuple" requirement?

Comment: @flyfisher Note that this makes a *copy* of the tuple data.  It doesn't allocate it on a heap.  In C++, structs are not views, they are actual memory.  You can't use a struct as a view into another type (barring some extreme corner cases).

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont: `std::make_from_tuple<foo>(std::move(a))` would at least change it from a copy to a move, though that will only matter if the members of the `tuple` are more efficient to move than to copy.

Comment: How about showing the OP how to construct `struct foo { const int &x; const std::string  &y; const some_big_type &z;};` from his tuple?  (And no, exactly what he wants is unclear to me too).

Comment: @Red.Wave Why are you passing 2 arguments to `make_from_tuple`?  And the data (as described by the OP) is going to be copied out of the tuple into the struct - how it happens doesn't change that fact.

Comment: @Red.Wave No, that isn't how `make_from_tuple` works; make from tuple takes 1 tuple and returns 1 object.  And if returning a struct of objects (like the OP describes), it copies the contents of the tuple into the objects.  So I am unclear what the point of the comment was; it appears to be talking about elision and RVO, but I'm not sure why you are mentioning it.  I mean, it happens, but what does that have to do with the problem at hand?

Comment: Right. I got mixed up.