# Most efficient way to populate an existing struct from a tuple in C++?

Tags: c++, performance

This is a followup to another question I asked earlier.

Say I have:

```
struct foo {
  int x;
  std::string y;
  some_big_class z;
};

foo s;
```

Now I am iterating over a bunch of `tuple<int, std::string, some_big_class>` and I would like to, for each tuple, populate s with the values from the tuple and then do something with `s`.

What is the most efficient way to do this, assuming I can `std::move` the tuples?

I could rewrite the struct to use a tuple as the storage, and then have a move constructor which takes the tuple, but that doesn't seem very elegant, since then all my accessors will have to keep track of which element in the tuple is "theirs", etc. (this example is just a toy example; my real struct has many more elements).

My previous question's solution involved using `std::make_from_tuple` to efficiently create a *new* foo object. This question is about efficiently transferring/moving the contents of a tuple into an *existing* foo object.

Comment: what's the difference with your previous question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76366567/is-there-a-way-to-move-a-stdtuple-into-a-struct

Comment: Why do the move at all?  What do you get from that?  Do you just want an easier way of accessing the members of the tuple?  If so, use a structured binding: `auto& [x, y, z] = tuple_element;`

Comment: I'm not sure you got a great answer to your original question, but this feels more like an attempt to clarify what you actually wanted (that still doesn't seem all that clear to me) and not actually a separate question.

Comment: @NathanOliver, I need to have a foo that I can send off to be used by other parts of the code, so I don't see how structured binding helps here... or am I missing something?

Comment: @NathanPierson I got an answer that works for constructing new objects from tuples, but this question is about filling in an existing object from a tuple, which I think is different because the space is already allocated

Comment: I was just asking a question.  You never mentioned you needed a `foo`, just that you would like to.  I was asking you about why you would like to.

Comment: Filling an existing object works the same, `foo s; s = aggregate_from_tuple(my_tuple);`

Comment: @NathanOliver do you mean `s = make_from_tuple(my_tuple);`? Wouldn't that create a new foo and then copy it to s? Apologies if I'm being an idiot.

Comment: It would make a new `foo`, and then that would be moved assigned into `s`.

Comment: Is there a need or demand for efficiency?  Would you prefer a safer method?

Comment: @flyfisher I would think that optimizing compilers do not create temporary objects and copy them around. Formally you'll need a default constructor and a 3-argument constructor but if they are side-effect free they'll not really be called. One S will be created directly.

Comment: In all reality, the fastest way to create a struct from a tuple with PODs would be to simply cast a pointer to the tuple to a pointer to the struct. The memory layout should be the same, but make sure the tuple elements are ordered inversely. (Sure, it's UB, make sure to compile with --fnostrict-aliasing (for gcc).)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
std::tie(s.x, s.y, s.z) = std::move(the_tuple);
```

This also lets you shuffle the element around if the order differs between the struct and the tuple or if there are more elements in the tuple than needed:

```
std::tie(s.x, s.z, std::ignore, s.y) = std::move(the_tuple);
```